# Meteor.js 0.6.5.1 and Bootstrap 3

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I installed Bootstrap 3 in my Meteor.js 0.6.5.1 project via meteorite and did a "meteor remove" of the originally packaged bootstrap 2.3.2.  But everytime I run "meteor" the old bootstrap package seems to be re-installed.  Now my meteor project has 2 versions of bootstrap being loaded and its giving me conflicts...anyway to permanently remove the old bootstrap or is it dependent as part of Meteor.js 0.6.5.1?

Answer (score 3):

You need to manually remove all the remnants of the package.

- Remove `packagename` from `.meteor/packages` file.
- Remove `/packages/packagename` folder. Also remove `packagename` from `/packages/.gitignore` if you've got that file.
- If you use meteorite, remove all traces of `packagename` from `smart.json` and force reload by running `mrt install`.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when I installed meteor-bootboxjs v3 it also installed bootstrap v2.3.x....next time I will look more closely @ the package.js.....